# Pretty new to sql and trying to figure out how to combine 2 tables in a nonstandard way

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot

I'm relatively new to SQL and I'm having trouble combining 2 models in a specific way. I think [PIVOT and UNPIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx?ppud=4) might help, but I find the docs very confusing. Consider the following problem:

You have two models. The first model is a list of questions on a test, like so:

Questions:

```
 id | Question
1   |  "What is 2+2"
2   |  "What is 3+4"
3   |  "What is 1+1"
...
```

And another table of all answers by each student, like so:

```
id | student_id | question_id| answer
 1 |          1 | 1          | "4" 
 2 |          1 |          2 | "I don't know" 
 1 |          2 |          1 | "3?" 
...
```

How would you output a table that had student_id vs question showing answer, like so:

```
student_id | "What is 2+2" | "What is 3+4"  | "What is 1+1" ...
         1 | "4"           | "I don't know" | null ...
         2 | "3?" ...
...
```

There might be hundreds of questions on this test so the column naming measure in the pivot docs would not work.

Comment: You have tagged postgres and linked to sql server docs. Are you using postgres or Sql server? This may help if you are on postgres http://www.craigkerstiens.com/2013/06/27/Pivoting-in-Postgres/

Comment: It sounds like you've found your answer: pivot. Unfortunately, you are correct in that you need to name the pivot columns. If there are hundreds of questions in the test do you really want a pivot result that is so wide?

Comment: check out the crosstab function in the `tablefunc` extension: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tablefunc.html